# Can't take out front wheel

Tags: wheels, quick-release

Someone messed up by quick release on the front wheel, so the side that says open is pointing outward. I can't undo the quick release now and take out the front wheel.

Comment: Pictures might help

Answer (score 1):

With the lever open, unscrew the nut on the other side a few turns.

Lefty loosey.

Comment: I tried that, but that seems to have no effect.

Comment: @a33b unscrew it until it comes off. Then you should be able to pull the skewer out.

Comment: @a33b Want to post an answer showing the world how you did it, what was wrong, and how to avoid it happening again?  Closure is helpful.    :ObligatoryXKCD: